# Filtering through a stream of maps and collecting into a single list?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'm still new to streams in Java, having trouble wrapping my mind around how to convert this into a single list or set:

I get sent in a List of SomeClassA objects which has a bunch of fields:

```
SomeClass: 
   String name
   String someId
   ...
   ImmutableMap<SomeCategory, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>> someMap
```

(the immutable collections are from: com.google.common.collect)

Given a list of SomeClassA, I want the result to be a single set of SomeClassB.

So a list of SomeClassA comes in, and I want to be able to go through it and get someMap, then filter out only certain categories, get out the list of SomeClassB, and then in the end combine all the lists.

I've tried a few different combinations of filters and maps, but always end up with the wrong types or extra streams. What's a simple way to do this?

```
return listOfSomeClassA.stream()
                 .map(objA -> objA.getSomeMap())
                 . // filter someMap entries by the map's keys of category - someCategory.equals("something")
                 . // put together all the lists of those categories == something??
```

Comment: Have a nice time with  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ&index=1&list=PLRsbF2sD7JVpQsKP-AQcTWEk-gj1RtyYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in filter method to filter out a stream by some condition.  If it evaluates to false it will be removed.

```
return listOfSomeClassA.stream()
    .flatMap(objA -> objA.getSomeMap().entrySet().stream())
    .filter(entry -> "something".equals(entry.getKey()))
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This will create a list of lists. OP wants to also flatten that into a single list.

Comment: You can use flatMap for that

Comment: hmm but the filter needs to be on the category which is the key, not the values (the list). Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: I modified my answer to use keys

Comment: +Kelvin, won't that just return the list of keys, not the list of values that correspond to the filtered keys? This would be the part I was having the most trouble with, so I'd really appreciate the help

Comment: I see, i updated it again, sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: `map()` and `flatMap()` can be combined to `flatMap(objA -> objA.getSomeMap().entrySet().stream())`

Comment: Of course, if your filter condition is `"something".equals(entry.getKey())`, then this is a waste of resources. Then, instead of `.flatMap(objA -> objA.getSomeMap().entrySet().stream()) .filter(entry -> "something".equals(entry.getKey()))` you could simply do `.map(objA -> objA.getSomeMap().get("something"))`